# Excel Excluding Certain Values from Duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data looks like that:

[image: Data Picture]

As you can see there are duplicated values in column B that have different values in column C.
I am trying to find a solution to remove some of them on certain conditions.
In column A there are different names of companies but in column B there are only 3 options (pending,ready,no). I would like to be able to have in column C a value: ready(if second duplicate has no or pending), pending(if second duplicate has value no).

I tried to do it with:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW($B$2:$B$9)-ROW($B$2)+1/($C$2:$C$9="no");ROWS($F$2:F2)));"")
```

But it does not solve my issue in the end.

Comment: What do you mean with column B have different values in column C. In your data you only show column A and B.

Comment: No no, I want to have in Column C a value depending on Column A and B.
As I wrote if in column A there are two duplicates with different values in Column B for example: Company Name A(A column) - no(B column), Company Name A(A column) - ready(B column) i would like to have in column C "ready"

Comment: @MatJablo Can you show your desired output from given data?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a third column that calculates the new value you want using specific logic. From your post, I am unsure of what this logic is.

1. if there is only one occurrence of the firm name, then the value is the same,
2. if multiple occurrences, what happens??
   if there are two occurences- one ready and one pending, what value do you want?
   if one is no and one is yes, what value do you want?

once you have a set of logic in mind, you can use if, countif, and countifs functions to solve it.

To get a count of the firm occurences:

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)`

To get a count of no,pending, and yes values:

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"no",$A$2:$A$7,$A2) =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"pending",$A$2:$A$7,$A2) =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"yes",$A$2:$A$7,$A2)`

you could then use a few nested ifs to perform your logic:

`=if(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)=1,B2,if(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,"no",$A$2:$A$7,$A2)=1,"no",etc))`